# WordPress Media Query

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I was trying to modify the CSS @media query of WordPress but it doesn't seems to work. in the browser inspector appears two lines of code (index:1733 and index:1104 containing the same code) but the line 1733 is the only one working.

What is happening? any help please.

Thank you in advance

[image: Media Query code]

[image: Code does not work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has a read order in which the code is read. What is happening here is that the second piece (index:1733) is overwriting the first piece (index:1104). Would seem that you have defined the CSS twice. So, if this is code you have written, then you could just find the line of code and rewrite it. If this is a plugin that you want to overwrite, then you could use `!important` in your CSS. I would advice against this last bit unless necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much! yes I am using a plugin and I was not able to find the code file to modify it manually so the code (!important) was very useful! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The code is working perfectly as it should.

You have written CSS for an element twice in a stylesheet. (1104 & 1733). So the CSS on the bottom of the stylesheet will override the CSS written on the top.

Comment: Thank you, how can I move my code to the bottom, from the WordPress CSS Editor? I can not find the (index) file to edit manually, it seems to be hidden in any PHP file I think, do you have a hint?

Comment: try adding your CSS to style.css file at the bottom by going to Appearances->themes->style.css
Or you can add "!important" to your style in the top itself. !important will be given first priority. I have edited my answer with example. Check above answer

Answer (score 0):

Reason is  line 1733 overriding the code on line 1104, either remove one of the code or change the media query as per the design